# switch statement with two variables at a time

Tags: php, switch-statement

Could someone suggest the best way to have the following switch statement? I don't know that it's possible to compare two values at once, but this would be ideal:

```
switch($color,$size){
    case "blue","small":
        echo "blue and small";
    break;

    case "red","large";
        echo "red and large";
    break;
}
```

---

This could be comparable to:

```
if (($color == "blue") && ($size == "small")) {
    echo "blue and small";
}
elseif (($color == "red") && ($size == "large")) {
    echo "red and large";
}
```

---

**Update**
I realized that I'll need to be able to negate `($color !== "blue")` and compare as opposed to equating variables to strings.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Answers below by @Stikmou and Renaat De Muynck meet the asker's question perfectly. Other answers, while certainly legitimate, are going about the solution in slightly different ways.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can change the order of the comparison, but this is still not ideal.

```
    switch(true)
    {
      case ($color == 'blue' and $size == 'small'):
        echo "blue and small";
        break;
      case ($color == 'red' and $size == 'large'):
        echo "red and large";
        break;
      default:
        echo 'nothing';
        break;
    }
```

Comment: hideously ugly, but not "wrong" either... better to go with a standard if() instead, if only for legibility.

Comment: Thanks! I agree.. could get messy, and probably will. I'm trying to see whether `switch` could make the if statement look nicer and easier to modify in the future.

Comment: I think it's perfect.  For the real world, this is what real developers use.

Answer (score 66):

Using the new array syntax, this looks almost like what you want:

```
switch ([$color, $size]) {
    case ['blue', 'small']:
        echo 'blue and small';
    break;

    case ['red', 'large'];
        echo 'red and large';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Doesn't work. You could hack around it with some string concatentation:

```
switch($color . $size) {
   case 'bluesmall': ...
   case 'redlarge': ...
}
```

but that gets ugly pretty quick.

Comment: Just be careful with ambiguous values that might not match ordinarily, e.g. switch on `'abc' . 'def'`, while the case is `'ab' . 'cdef'`. two different sets of values, but producing the same concatenated result.

Comment: won't be a problem for what i'm doing, but thats a good point to bring up. Anyway thanks for the trick!

Comment: Might be worth adding a separating character between the strings, maybe just a simple comma or uncommonly used character (eg pipe)? example: $color.','.$size then compare 'blue,small'

Comment: I think Scuzzy might have the correct answer. I can't think of a way to negate one variable in a case here, i.e. `casce 'blue !small'` wouldn't be feasible this way, right?

Comment: a 'not' of a string will simply be a boolean false value. if you do need to negate stuff or test for inequality, then switch to a normal if/then/else structure. case statements are for multiple equality tests on a single core value. this concatenation is simply an abusive extension of that, but you can't fundamentally change the fact that's still just an equality test.

Comment: Just try the next scenario... $color=3 and $size=20; and let's see if this is a good idea. Per default php will treat this as 3.2 instead of "3.20" so your scenario failed.

Answer (score 7):

Found at  http://www.siteduzero.com/forum/sujet/switch-a-plusieurs-variables-75351

```
<?php
$var1 = "variable1";
$var2 = "variable2";
$tableau = array($var1, $var2);

switch ($tableau){
    case array("variable1", "variable2"):
        echo "Le tableau correspond !";
    break;

    case array(NULL, NULL):
        echo "Le tableau ne correspond pas.";
    break; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your other option (though not pretty) is to nest the switch statements:

```
switch($color){
    case "blue":
        switch($size):
            case "small":
            //do something
            break;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $var1 = "something";
var $var2 = "something_else";
switch($var1.$var2) {
case "somethingsomething_else":
    ...
    break;
case "something...":
    break;
case "......":
    break;
}
```